# cannot add a user to a Google Cloud project

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I try to add a user to a project using IAM & Admin -> IAM -> Grant Access, but I get the error message

```
A domain restriction organization policy is in place. Only principals in allowed domains can be added as principals in the policy. Correct the principal emails and try again.
```

What can I do? Especially, I changed to Org Policy "Domain Restricted Sharing" and it does not immediately work. Do I just have to wait?

Answer (score 0):

Waiting solved the issue, don't despair :)